# Why is .map being added to the end of my file path?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to enqueue a js plugin file to my wordpress theme but I keep getting a 404 error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This is the file path URL: http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/octagon-business-group/js/jquery.fullpage.min.js.map

The file path is correct and when I remove the '.map' it takes me to the correct file. I'm not sure why it was added.

This is the way I have enqueued the file:

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin-full-page-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fullPage.min.js', array(), '20151215', true );
```

Does anyone know why the .map was added and how I could remove it?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/how-to-use-javascript-source-maps-map-files#:~:text=The%20.,files%20that%20have%20been%20minified.&text=When%20your%20app%20is%20in,original%20version%20of%20the%20code.) is an Answer that might help?